# C Memory Allocation: Why there is not enough memory(250K only)

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I am having trouble figuring out the reason why my .c code is having trouble allocating ~250K of memory. Here is the allocation code:

```
struct IMAGE {
    int width, height, maxval;
    char **data;
};

void raiseError(char *msg)
{
    printf("%s", msg);
    getch();
    exit(1);
}

//...

IMAGE readPGM()
{
    IMAGE image;
    image.data = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char)*image.height);

    //..

    for (i=0; i<image.height; i++) {
        image.data[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*image.width);
        if (image.data[i]=='\0') {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            raiseError("Not enough memory!..");
        }
    }

    //..
}

//..
```

The program exits when i=116. image.width and image.height equals to 500 here, so I want 500x500=250000 bytes to be allocated here. But 116x500 = 58000 bytes are being allocated at maximum. So, is there something that limits it? Is there something wrong with my code? I am posting the full source below, just in case if it is necesarry. The idea is to read a PGM file into the structure IMAGE, process it and rewrite it in another file. As you can tell, it is not complete yet because I couldn't figure out a way to allocate more memory.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<alloc.h>
struct IMAGE {
    int width, height, maxval;
    char **data;
};

void raiseError(char *msg)
{
    printf("%s", msg);
    getch();
    exit(1);
}

char *toString(int num)
{
    char sign = 0;
    if (num<0) {
        sign = -1;
        num*=-1;
    }
    int numLen = 1;
    if (sign<0) {
        numLen++;
    }
    int tmpNum = num;
    while (tmpNum>9) {
        tmpNum /= 10;
        numLen++;
    }
    char *result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(numLen+1));
    result[numLen] = '\0';
    char ch;
    while (num>9) {
        ch = (num%10)+'0';
        num /= 10;
        result[numLen-1] = ch;
        numLen--;
    }
    result[numLen-1] = num + '0';

    if (sign<0)
        result[0] = '-';
    return result;
}

int toInteger(char *line)
{
    int i=strlen(line)-1;
    int factor = 1;
    int result = 0;
    while (i>=0) {
        result += factor*(line[i]-'0');
        factor *= 10;
        i--;
    }
    return result;
}

char *getNewParam(FILE *fp)
{
    char ch = 'X';
    char *newParam;
    newParam = (char*) malloc(1);
    newParam[0] = '\0';
    int paramSize = 0;
    while (!isspace(ch)) {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (!isspace(ch)) {
            if (ch=='#') {
                while (fgetc(fp)!='\n');
                continue;
            }
            paramSize++;
            newParam = (char *) realloc(newParam, paramSize+1);
            newParam[paramSize-1] = ch;
        }
    }
    newParam[paramSize] = '\0';
    return newParam;
}

IMAGE readPGM()
{
    FILE *fp;
    IMAGE image;
    //Open the file.
    fp = fopen("seeds2.pgm","r+b");
    if (fp=='\0')
        raiseError("File could not be opened!..");

    //Check if it is a raw PGM(P5)
    char *line;
    line = getNewParam(fp);
    if (strcmp(line, "P5")!=0)
        raiseError("File is not a valid raw PGM(P5)");
    int paramCount = 0;
    int *pgmParams;
    pgmParams = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    while (paramCount<3) {
        line = getNewParam(fp);
        pgmParams[paramCount++] = toInteger(line);
    }
    int pixelSize;
    if (pgmParams[2]>255)
        pixelSize = 2;
    else
        pixelSize = 1;

    image.width =pgmParams[0];
    image.height =pgmParams[1];
    image.maxval =pgmParams[2];
    free(pgmParams);
    image.data = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char)*image.height);
    int i,j;
    long sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i<image.height; i++) {
        image.data[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*image.width);
        sum += sizeof(char)*image.width;
        if (image.data[i]=='\0') {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            raiseError("Not enough memory!..");

        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<image.height; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<image.width; j++) {
            fread(&image.data[i][j], sizeof(char), image.width, fp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return image;
}

void savePGM(IMAGE image)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("yeni.pgm", "w+b");
    fprintf(fp, "P5\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",
        toString(image.width), toString(image.height), toString(image.maxval));
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<image.height; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<image.width; j++) {
            fwrite(&image.data[i][j], sizeof(char), 1, fp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    IMAGE image = readPGM();
    //process
    savePGM(image);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `conio.h`? What compiler are you using?

Comment: i'm using IDE, Borland Turbo c++, v3.0.

Comment: @hrnt: you can use conio.h with visual studio c/c++ compiler and it also works on devc++ compiler

Comment: The question is about memory allocation, why are you getting hung up about the use of conio?  Besides Microsoft's conio and Borland's are not identical - that is what non-standard means ;)

Comment: Using conio.h usually implies the use of Turbo C++, and use of Turbo C++ usually implies the use of 16-bit compiler which usually causes problems when allocations approach 64k limit :) That is why I asked which compiler was being used.

Comment: You are allocating enough memory for image.height char. And then you try to store image.height char* in that memory. Shit is going to happen, and it did.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the comment you added to it.  You are using an (antique) 16 bit x86 real mode compiler.  A 16 bit virtual machine can address only 1Mb of memory in total, only 640Kb of which is normally accessible to programs, and is shared with the OS.

**[edit in response to paxdiablo's comment]**

Further to those restrictions the segmented addressing architecture also gives rise to a number of *memory models* where as little as 64kb may be the limit for specific memory areas.

Also the argument to malloc() has type size_t, which may only be 16-bit in this case - you should check.  I recall using a variant called halloc() for large allocations.  But short of using a DOS extender, there is still a 640kb limit.

**[end edit]**

There are a number of far better and free modern 32-bit compilers available.  Dump the antique.  I suggest [VC++ Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/VC/)

Apart from that strictly:

```
if(image.data[i]=='\0')
```

should be

```
if(image.data[i]==0)
```

or

```
if(image.data[i]==NULL)
```

As it happens it will work in either case, but technically you are testing for a null-pointer not a NUL character.

Comment: +1 but with one proviso. Turbo C (IIRC) had memory models, where you could have 64K for code/data/stack (tiny), and then various other options up to separate 64K each for code, data and stack (large). But I think there was a huge memory model which allowed multiple 64K segments for data. I cannot recall whether *each* data structure was still limited to 64K though. Caveat: I haven't used Borland for *many* years, my memory may be faulty. But Clifford is correct, get yourself a more modern compiler. VC Express, gcc, CodeBlocks, none of them cost any money.

Comment: I guess that seems to be the problem, I should have noticed that when I saw I could allocate 58000 at maxiumum. And @paxdiablo, I have tried to use the huge model, but it looks like each data structure is still limited to 64K.

Comment: Does the Turbo C library support halloc()?  The problem is probably that size_t is 16bit, halloc() accepts a 32bit argument.  However I only ever used this on Microsoft's DOS compilers, so it may not be supported or may have a different name.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not going to read all that code -- this is a prime example of where you should give a minimal example to reproduce the problem -- but this line:

```
image.data = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char)*image.height);
```

is incorrect.  It should have `sizeof(char*)`.  The statement as written should return a `char*` but you are casting it to `char**`.

FWIW, on my system, `sizeof(char)` returns 1 and `sizeof(char*)` returns 4, because a `char` is a single byte, and a `char*` is a pointer (aka a single word of 32 bits).  So you actually allocated 1/4 of what you probably intended to allocate.

Comment: Also, sizeof(char) is always 1, by definition.  There's no need to ever write sizeof(char) * X.

Comment: Moreover, you may corrupting your pointers when executing `image.data[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*image.width);` as you may overwrite the end of the pointer returned by malloc.
Another problem is that `image.data[i]=='\0'`tests only the first byte of that pointer.

Comment: @swegi: `image.data[i] == '\0'` is actually ok, but it should be rewritten.  `'\0'` is equivalent to `0`, which is equivalent to `NULL`, so it's the same as testing `image.data[i] == NULL`.

Comment: @Mark: I have corrected that mistake of mine, but now it exits when i=113, so it didn't help. 

And by the way, when I run the .EXE without the IDE, it allocates the memory without returning any '\0'. But when I open the file I created, I can tell that there was some corruption with the pointers like swegi pointed out, because it's not the data I want, it's some other memory block which happens to be there, probably. I'll look into it in the morning though, thanks for all the help.

Comment: @AdamR, you're right that the effect is the same but I tend to use NULL exclusively for pointers. I'll use '\0' for character 0 since it seems to convey the intent better. Interestingly (to me) though, 0 is used for integers but I don't follow through and use 0L or 0.0 for longs and floating point (or U/LL/ULL for unsigned and the long longs).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I'll be using a new compiler and I beleive this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you print out the value that you are passing to malloc, you will find out how much memory you are really asking for.