# C can't allocate enough memory

Tags: c, malloc

Below code doesn't give any allocation error , however the counting ends at about 16970 with memory allocation error and system halted
,I use Turbo C++ 3.0 IDE
,Windows XP sp3
, all partitions : NTFS
,PC : Dell 1545 with 2 GB ram installed .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long counter=0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char* array=(char*) malloc (1024*1024*10);
        if (array==NULL) 
            {
                /* allocation error */
                return 1;
            }
         for (counter=0 ; counter<10000000;counter++)
         array[counter] = 1;  // trying to fill the array with one's
        free (array);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Meninx: in what universe would this be? `1024*1024*10 -> 10,485,760`, which most definitely not smaller than `10,000,000`

Comment: any reason you're specifying a char array, and then filling it with integers?

Comment: I see now that you are using a `C++` compiler, that's why you need to cast `malloc`

Comment: @MarcB confused by the zeroes !

Comment: @MarcB why shouldn't a `char` array be filled with `1`?

Comment: @MarcB: The `1` is converted to type `char` by assignment.

Comment: TC++ .. again.. Get rid of this antique already!

Comment: Turbo C++ 3.0 is very old.  Is it possible that its `int`s are only 16 bits wide?

Comment: Try printing the evaluation of `1024*1024*10` and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: Or print `sizof(int)` .

Comment: What @WeatherVane said... my bet is that 1024*1024*10 wrapped due to a 16-bit int.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with my 21st century compiler.

Comment: From wikipedia: *Turbo C++ 3.0 was released in 1991* - It's even older than I though...

Comment: If `malloc`'s `size_t` argument is greater then 16 bits, and your `int` is 16-bits, you should cast the multiplication like `(size_t)1024*1024*10`. Assuming Turbo C has a `size_t` otherwise use `(long)1024*1024*10`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658579/c-memory-allocation-why-there-is-not-enough-memory250k-only?rq=1)

Comment: @Gustavo that question is related, but the issue here is that the compiler truncates 1024*1024*10 to a 16-bit integer as 0. Malloc isn't running out of memory trying to allocate a large space, instead it's being told to allocate zero memory.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you , that was very helpful  .

Answer (score 4):

Turbo C++ worked in a DOS environment, in real mode unless you specifically enable protected mode. In real mode, memory space is broken into 64kbyte segments, and size_t (the parameter for malloc) could easily be 16 bits. 1024*1024*10 mod 65536 = 0, so the call to malloc above works out to `malloc(0)`.

The return value of malloc(0) is implementation-defined, and may be nonzero. ([what does malloc(0) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132273/what-does-malloc0-return)) Using the returned pointer would be a bad idea, and Windows XP might be intervening with the memory allocation error.

Comment: ( 1024*1024*10 mod 65536 = 0, so the call to malloc above works out to malloc(0) )    ,, this should return a 'NULL' pointer , but that wouldn't happen !

Comment: so , the problem here is in the TC++ compiler ? then , should I  replace it ?

Comment: @howard Yes, you should replace this compiler with something newer.  (And you should probably replace Windows XP with something newer, while you're at it. ;-)

Comment: what about 'farmalloc'  ? at all I should finish this project with ms dos compilers

Comment: @Howard: `malloc(0)` is allowed to return a valid pointer to zero bytes of memory.